# remove extra (^@) from visual selection

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I'm writing a function to execute an external command using visual selection.
I've noticed that if by mistake the entire line is selected, including the new line char the extra `^@` character makes the shell command to fail:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_BitwiseOperator:
line   18:
E485: Can't read file /tmp/v5rPHeq/9
```

I know I can just trim the last character if it matches `^@`, but I'm wondering if I am missing something.

My `BitwiseOperation` function looks this:

```
function! s:BitwiseOperator(type)
  let saved_unnamed_register = @@
  if a:type ==# 'v'
        normal! `<v`>y
    elseif a:type ==# 'char'
        normal! `[v`]y
    else
        return
    endif

  botright new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  silent execute '$read !'. "bitwise --no-color ". shellescape(@@)
  setlocal nomodifiable
  let @@ = saved_unnamed_register
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up trimming the newline charachter using search/replace.

```
substitute(a:string, '\n\+$', '', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `^@` you're referring to is actually a newline character, so the problem you describe will happen when your visual selection includes the newline (e.g. `v$` to select until the end of the line) or when it spawns multiple lines.

Assuming your external tool you're shelling out to is able to handle multiline strings appropriately, Vim's [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) will be able to handle it in a way that the shell will interpret it correctly, by turning it into a single quoted string that can embed newlines.

So `multiline\n` becomes `'multiline\n'` through `shellescape()` (where the `\n` here represents an actual newline character), and the shell is fine with it.

The problem you're having is that `:execute` is now seeing two separate commands, in this case:

```
$read !bitwise --no-color 'multiline
```

And:

```
'
```

Or, more geneally, for `first line\nsecond line`:

```
$read !bitwise --no-color 'first line
second line'
```

There are two possible solutions to this problem. The first is to pass a non-zero second argument to [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29), which will make it do some extra magic to handle cases like this one with the newline. From [`:help shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29):

> With a non-zero-arg `{special}` the `<NL>` character is also escaped. [...]
>
> Example of use with a `:!` command:
>
> ```
> :exe '!dir ' . shellescape(expand('<cfile>'), 1)
> ```

The example itself is using `: execute`, so it's actually a good illustration of your issue.

So one possible solution is:

```
silent execute '$read !'. "bitwise --no-color ". shellescape(@@, 1)
```

Another, actually better solution, is to use the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function to shell out instead, in which case you don't need to worry about escaping the string from `:execute`.

In order to put the contents of the `system()` result into the new buffer, you can use the [`:put`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput) command together with the [`@=` expression register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%40%3D).

Putting it all together:

```
silent put =system('bitwise --no-color '.shellescape(@@))
```

You can also use [`setline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29) instead of `:put`, which makes it even easier to get rid of the empty line at the start of the buffer. With `setline()`, use `systemlist()`, to get the shell output as a list of lines:

```
call setline(1, systemlist('bitwise --no-color '.shellescape(@@)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `shellescape(@@, 1)` just introduces an escape `\` character before the ^@

Comment: It actually adds a backslash before the newline... It works, but the other solutions using `system()` (or `systemlist()`) are better, since you don't need that extra level of escaping...